# Google Charts - 'labeled' legend does not line up with

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, line

I'm not quite sure as to what I am doing wrong. When I run all this code, the legend is a little skewed and off center. I want each legend item to be next to the corresponding line. Is there a way to align the legend so that it is right next to the corresponding line? I have provided the code below. I've tried to solve the legend by using different options. But they don't seem to work.

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'X');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Bowser');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Captain Falcon');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Donkey Kong');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Dr. Mario');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Falco');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Fox');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Ganondorf');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Ice Climbers');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Jigglypuff');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Kirby');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Link');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Luigi');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Mario');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Marth');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Mewtwo');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Mr. Game & Watch');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Ness');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Peach');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Pichu');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Pikachu');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Roy');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Samus');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Sheik');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Yoshi');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Young Link');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Zelda');

    data.addRows([
        [1,  24, 15, 19, 10,  2,  2, 11, 11, 17, 22, 13,  6,  5,  4, 26, 23, 17,  9, 24, 13, 21,  6,  1, 19, 15,  6],
        [2,  22, 12, 20,  7,  3,  2, 10, 12, 10, 22, 14,  9,  6,  5, 25, 22, 14,  4, 26, 17, 20,  8,  1, 18, 18, 14],
        [3,  26, 11, 21,  7,  3,  2, 12, 13, 10, 23, 18,  8,  6,  4, 24, 22, 15,  5, 25, 16, 17,  9,  1, 14, 19, 20],
        [4,  26, 11, 21,  8,  5,  2, 10, 15,  9, 23, 18, 12,  7,  3, 24, 22, 17,  4, 25, 13, 20,  6,  1, 14, 19, 16],
        [5,  26,  7, 22, 10,  5,  3,  8, 18, 11, 21, 14, 12,  9,  2, 23, 24, 20,  4, 25, 16, 15,  6,  1, 13, 17, 19],
        [6,  25,  6, 21, 11,  4,  2,  9, 15,  8, 22, 13, 12, 10,  3, 24, 23, 20,  5, 26, 14, 16,  7,  1, 19, 18, 17],
        [7,  24,  6, 16,  9,  5,  2, 10, 12,  8, 22, 14, 13, 11,  3, 25, 23, 19,  4, 26, 17, 15,  7,  1, 21, 20, 18],
        [8,  23,  6, 15,  9,  2,  1, 12,  7, 10, 24, 13, 14, 11,  4, 26, 21, 22,  5, 25, 18, 16,  8,  3, 19, 17, 20],
        [9,  23,  6, 13, 10,  4,  1, 11,  8,  6, 25, 15, 12, 14,  2, 24, 20, 21,  5, 26, 16, 18,  9,  3, 22, 17, 19],
        [10, 24,  7, 15,  9,  2,  1, 10,  8,  3, 25, 16, 14, 13,  5, 20, 22, 23,  6, 25, 12, 19, 11,  4, 21, 17, 18],
        [11, 24,  7, 17,  9,  2,  1, 12,  8,  5, 26, 16, 13, 14,  4, 21, 22, 23,  6, 25, 10, 20, 11,  3, 18, 15, 19],
        [12, 25,  8, 17, 11,  2,  1, 14,  7,  5, 26, 18, 13, 15,  3, 21, 19, 23,  6, 24,  9, 20, 10,  4, 12, 16, 22],
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'Character Tiers Over Time',
        theme: 'material',
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Tier List',
            gridlines: {
                count: 12
            }
        },
        vAxis: {
            title: 'Placing',
            gridlines: {
                count: 27
            },
            viewWindow: {
                max: 26,
                min: 1
            }
        },
        legend: {
            position: 'labeled'
        },
        height: 1000
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiLgs.png

Here's a link to an image of the chart.